# Flask - URL is wrong when i login

Tags: python, html, authentication, url, flask

I have a problem today, and i need to resolve it to pass in another task.
When I want to log in, the connection is done without problem, however when I connect the url remains in "http://127.0.0.1/login" but displays my page index.html on this link. And I don't understand why I can't directly go to my "http://127.0.0.1/index" directory directly with my index.html.
At the end of my login function, instead of putting "return render_template('index.html', **templateData)" I put "index()" directly as in logout but I have the error code 500

I can share all of my directory python if you need.

Best regards
(sorry for my bad english .. !)

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        if app.NOM == '':
            return render_template('login.html', login=1)
        else:
            var = "SELECT users.prenom, users.nom, data.bpm, data.oxy, data.chute FROM data, users WHERE users.ID = '" + str(app.ID) + "' AND data.User = '" + str(app.ID) + "' ORDER BY data.User DESC LIMIT 1 "
            try:
                cur = bdd_login()
            except pymysql.Error as e:
                return session_out(e)
            result = cur.execute(var)
            cur.close()
            print(result)
            if not result:
                bpm = 0
                oxy = 0
                chute = 0
            else:
                for row in cur:
                    print(row)
                bpm = row[2]
                oxy = row[3]
                chute = row[4]
                templateData = {'prenom': app.PRENOM, 'nom': app.NOM, 'rank': app.RANK, 'bpm': bpm, 'oxy': oxy}
                if bpm < 40 or bpm > 100:
                    if oxy < 80:
                        if chute == 0:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=0, state_oxy=0, state_chute=0)
                        else:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=0, state_oxy=0, state_chute=1)
                    elif 95 <= oxy <= 100:
                        if chute == 0:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=0, state_oxy=1, state_chute=0)
                        else:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=0, state_oxy=1, state_chute=1)
                    elif 80 <= oxy < 95:
                        if chute == 0:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=0, state_oxy=2, state_chute=0)
                        else:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=0, state_oxy=2, state_chute=1)
                elif 60 <= bpm <= 80:
                    if oxy < 80:
                        if chute == 0:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=1, state_oxy=0, state_chute=0)
                        else:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=1, state_oxy=0, state_chute=1)
                    elif 95 <= oxy <= 100:
                        if chute == 0:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=1, state_oxy=1, state_chute=0)
                        else:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=1, state_oxy=1, state_chute=1)
                    elif 80 <= oxy < 95:
                        if chute == 0:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=1, state_oxy=2, state_chute=0)
                        else:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=1, state_oxy=2, state_chute=1)
                elif 40 <= bpm < 60 or 80 < bpm <= 100:
                    if oxy < 80:
                        if chute == 0:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=2, state_oxy=0, state_chute=0)
                        else:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=2, state_oxy=0, state_chute=1)
                    elif 95 <= oxy <= 100:
                        if chute == 0:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=2, state_oxy=1, state_chute=0)
                        else:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=2, state_oxy=1, state_chute=1)
                    elif 80 <= oxy < 95:
                        if chute == 0:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=2, state_oxy=2, state_chute=0)
                        else:
                            return render_template('index.html', **templateData, state_bpm=2, state_oxy=2, state_chute=1)


@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    POST_NAME = str(request.form['nom'])
    POST_PRENOM = str(request.form['prenom'])
    POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])
    var = "SELECT id, nom, prenom, password, privilege FROM users WHERE nom = '" + POST_NAME + "' AND password = '" + POST_PASSWORD + "' AND prenom = '" + POST_PRENOM + "'"
    try:
        cur = bdd_login()
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        return session_out(e)
    result = cur.execute(var)
    cur.close()
    for row in cur:
        print(row)
    if result:
        session.permanent = True
        session['logged_in'] = True
        session['prenom'] = POST_PRENOM
        session['nom'] = POST_NAME
        session['ID'] = row[0]
        if row[4] == 'patient':
            session['rank'] = 0
        if row[4] == 'proche':
            session['rank'] = 1
        if row[4] == 'med':
            session['rank'] = 2
        if row[4] == 'admin':
            session['rank'] = 3
        app.NOM = session['nom']
        app.PRENOM = session['prenom']
        app.RANK = session['rank']
        app.ID = session['ID']
        templateData = {'prenom': app.PRENOM, 'nom': app.NOM, 'rank': app.RANK}
        return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
    else:
        return render_template('login.html', login=0)


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session['logged_in'] = False
    session.pop('prenom', None)
    session.pop('nom', None)
    session.pop('ID', None)
    session.pop('rank', None)
    app.PRENOM = ""
    app.NOM = ""
    app.RANK = ""
    app.ID = ""
    return index()
```

Comment: Login : http://prntscr.com/r2ddmx

When i login : http://prntscr.com/r2de69

And i need to click on dashboard to have this : http://prntscr.com/r2deoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly, you are dealing with below problems

1. After login, its showing `index` page but URL is not changing.
2. after logout its throwing error.

basically you are rendering `index.html` template inside `login` route, you have to redirect after a successful login request.

you can not directly call `index()` inside `logout`, treat these as routes not like normal functions

Comment: Yes he show index.html with url /login
However, for the logout, i have no problem and the index() works

Comment: I don't see where I should do it after successful login, because for me that's when I need to send to index.html

Comment: Instead of rendering index.html inside login redirect to index route

Comment: How i do the redirect to index route without my function index() ?

Comment: you can do this way `return redirect(url_for('index'))`

Comment: Thank you .. i try this 2 hours ago and error 500 ... but now its works. Thank you @Sanjay

Comment: ok, if my suggestion helped to resolve your problem then accept the answer.